# inclusion of component angular 4 declaration

Tags: angular, components

I would like to dissociate in 2 components my menu and my modal.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-primary">
     <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" (click)="clickButton()" >
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">{{menu_title}}</a>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
             <li class="nav-item active">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a  (click)="open(content)" class="nav-link" href="#">Ajouter</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#quitter">Quitter</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
         <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
             <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
             <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button> -->
         </form>
     </div>
 </nav>

 <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
     <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
         <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
         <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
     </div>
 </ng-template>
```

as soon as I separate my 'ng-template' and my 'nav" in 2 differents
 components, I have an error. for example (one component
 "nav.component" with the nav) and one componen "modal.component" with
 the ng-template and the class "ModalComponent"

> NavComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: co.open is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NavComponent.html:13)
>       at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11798)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13006)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12594)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8773)
>       at core.es5.js:9363
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (platform-browser.es5.js:2683)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.526.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4116)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.526.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.526.Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)

but If I write all the html in **ONE** component the one who has the
 ModalComponent class of course

```
 export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

     closeResult: string;

     constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

     open(content) {
         this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
             this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
         }, (reason) => {
             this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
         });
     }

     private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
         if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
             return 'by pressing ESC';
         }
         else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK)
         {
             return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
         }
         else
         {
             return  `with: ${reason}`;
         }
     }

     ngOnInit() {

     }

 }
```

it works perfectly.

the in fact i don't have a problem to make it run, but as I like to
 have a good structure, I would like to know if it was possible to
 dissociate one component in 2? (I have spent 4 hours to try all
 combinaisons (changing the order of import modul in my app.module
 etc.... calling my components from different way in root ,) nothing to
 do.

Here is the structure I would like to have. But the application force
 me to have either nav either modal. [![enter image description
 here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mptkR.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mptkR.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help!:)

Comment: A little confusing. What is your template code showing? You can create your own component granularity as you want. 2 or 3 or even more won't have problem. Just import it and use its 'selector' (directive).

Comment: Well in a way you're right  I don't manage to import one component in another. even if I do import { component} ... in my component and If I use the selector directive in my template. The import is not made correctly  to allow the merge of the both codes. This is my problem in this case, NavComponent and ModalComponent are not imported correctly in menuComponent...so MenuComponent miss the instruction of ModalComponent...

Comment: When I use ` <a  (click)="open(content)" class="nav-link" href="#">Ajouter</a>` in my nav template, Angular does not recognize open methode even If it is existing in ModalComponent that I have imported. I will try to read again lessons I must miss something..

Comment: open(content) is in ModalComponent. You cannot directly refer to it from another component. It should be accessible within the scope of ng-template. However, you are using it outside it which is invalid.